# Before send .ajax (JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello and first of all thanks. That problem is taking me mad.

I've a form which is send through .ajax object. The code works fine, but doesn't when i try to add a 'beforesend' in the object.

I've this 'span' tag aside the button submit on the index.php

```
<input id="registrar-btn" type="button"> <span id="in-progress"> 0 </span>
```

And i'd like to change the '0' to "Processing data" text, i've looked for all the post here and every line seems to be ok!

I put there the .ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registrar_ciu.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#in-pogress").html("Processing daata");
            },
            success: function(){
            alert("Ciudadano "+nombre_apellido+" registrado con exito!");
            }
    });
```

So as you can see, the beforesend seems to be ok. I'll thank you each answer!

Comment: The name of key is `beforeSend`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: It worked, thank you and i feel really a fool

Comment: There is another typo. You have misspelled 'progress' in jQuery selector.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thank you! I've already fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `beforeSend` (capital S), the name is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, i still can't believe how it happenned

Comment: Natarr dont worry, I once spent 4 days trying to find an AJAX error when I forgot to put the period in front of Ajax $.ajax